# Channel the VPN through a WiFi hotspot

Tags: wifi, vpn, ip, hotspot

Suppose that I have my mobile connect with a VPN and I use my mobile as a WiFi router to provide internet to a laptop.
If I check my ip from the mobile, it is correctly the ip of VPN while if I check it from the laptop it is the one of my mobile ISP.
Why?
I thought the connection would be channelled through the VPN also for the laptop.
How could I solve this?

Comment: The VPN app on the phone tunnels your phone's traffic through the VPN. The mobile hotspot is a network outside of this. We have a duplicate of this, and I'm trying to find it.

Comment: Thank you I would really appreciate that. I can't find it.